# Does a countably generated $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra inject into some $p$-adic field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-numbers

Let $K$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$. If $K$ is finitely generated over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $K$ injects into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some $p$.

> > Assume that $K$ is countably generated, i.e., $K= \mathbb{Q}(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. Does there exist a prime $p$ such that $K$ injects into $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (or a finite field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$)?

Comment: What about the field $K$ obtained by adjoining a square root of every prime $p$ to $\mathbb{Q}$?  That is countably generated, yet it cannot embed into any extension $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @JasonStarr You are absolutely right. Of course, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ can't be embedded in any finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ either...

Comment: On the other hand, $\Bbb Q_p$ has transcendence degree $2^{\aleph_0}$ over $\Bbb Q$, so that you can embed any _purely transcendental_ extension $\Bbb Q(T_i  \mid  i \in I)$ in $\Bbb Q_p$ whenever $p$ is prime any $|I| \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I'm sure all of you are familiar, but for reference, the finitely generated case is covered by the Cassels embedding theorem, which ensures an embedding into infinitely many $\mathbb{Q}_p$.